spl-token transfer to multiple wallets using smart contract
I want to transfer spl token to multiple wallets using smart contract.
this is my contract:
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer as SplTransfer};

declare_id!("DDGa2CL5TNgnL5wBJXdn3RcZugKmcwNzxsZ422os6HYt");

#[program]
pub mod solana_multi_airdrop {
    use super::*;

    pub fn transfer_spl_tokens<'info>(
        ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, SplTokenTransfer<'info>>,
        amount: u64
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // Assuming `source_account` is correctly typed and initialized
        let source_account = &ctx.accounts.source_token_account;
        let token_program = &ctx.accounts.spl_token_program;
        let authority = &ctx.accounts.authority;
        let recipients = ctx.remaining_accounts.iter();

        // Iterate over recipients
        for recipient in recipients {
            // Create CPI accounts with correct references
            let cpi_accounts = SplTransfer {
                from: source_account.to_account_info().clone(),
                to: recipient.clone(), // Ensure this is valid
                authority: authority.to_account_info().clone(), // Ensureu this is valid
            };
            let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info(); // Ensure this is valid

            // Perform the transfer
            token::transfer(CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts), amount)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SplTokenTransfer<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub source_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub spl_token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}

I want to integrate this contract with frontend.
this is my code snippet for frontend integration.
      .accounts({
        authority: publicKey,
        sourceTokenAccount: sourceTokenAccount,
        splTokenProgram: solanaTokenAddress
      })
      .remainingAccounts(
        userAddress
      )
      .transaction();

      console.log("transaction >>>", transaction);

      const txSignature = await sendTransaction(
        transaction,
        connection
      )

But this script has occurred this error.
    at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (adapter.js:216:23)
    at async eval (WalletProviderBase.js:160:16)
    at async doSolAirDrop (index.js:399:27)

Can you please help me?

are these the full error logs? My best guess would be that, if you are using the public RPC endpoint, you are getting rate-limited

I had two concerns.
The first is about the arguments of sendTransaction.
Since you are passing two arguments, I believe you are passing either versionedTransaction and SendOptions, or the deprecated Transaction and Signer[].
It doesn’t seem to be versionedTransaction, so the second argument should be Signer[] instead of connection.

Moreover, if you are not setting the private key in the code and letting the user sign it, this method cannot be used.
In that case, you can change the ".transaction()" part to ".instruction()" in:
 .accounts({
        authority: publicKey,
        sourceTokenAccount: sourceTokenAccount,
        splTokenProgram: solanaTokenAddress
      })
      .remainingAccounts(
        userAddress
      )
      .transaction();

By doing sendAndConfirm(transaction), you can prompt the user to sign.
The second concern is about token.
Currently, token2022 is often used, so there might be a program mismatch.
Lastly, I recently made something similar to send PYUSD.
https://github.com/ytakahashi2020/pyusd_transfer
I stored the program in lib.rs and deployed it independently on Solana Playground.
I hope this is helpful.

Hello, thanks for your kind guidance. it's really helpful.
But I have some problem. I used your codebase and got error from phantom like "Dpp could be malicious"
Do you know how can I solve this problem?
Cheers.
